# jQuery menu slide up/down div, but also slide divs inside right/left

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, menu

I hope someone can help me, because I have stumbled upon an issue for me with some jquery. What I'm trying to figure out is:

1. Add class "active" = so it's possible to style  tags when active.
2. Vertical slide up/down div (#information (wrapper for "About" and "Contact")).
3. Horizontal slide left/right between page divs (between "About" and "Contact".)
4. If either "About" or "Contact" should be the active "page" and is displayed, then if clicked again on "About" link it should close slide up the #information wrapper.

[**This is what I got so far: JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/MSChristensen/zqup4ryv/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="information">
     <div id="info-about"></div>
     <div id="info-contact"></div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><a id="about" class="page" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a id="contact" class="page" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#information {
    width: 200%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

#info-about {
    width: 50%;
    height: inherit;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

#info-contact {
    width: 50%;
    height: inherit;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    if ($(this).is('.page.active')) {
        $('#information').slideDown('slow');
    }
});

$('#about').click(function () {
    $('#information').animate({
        left: "0"
    }, 1000);
});

$('#contact').click(function () {
    $('#information').animate({
        left: "-100%"
    }, 1000);
});
```

If anyone should be able to help me it would be very much appreciated. Furthermore, I'm not sure, but would it be possible to do it all as one combined script and not divided into parts?

Kind regards, Morten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after https://jsfiddle.net/c01gat3/wa1e8oyv/

```
$('li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('#information').slideUp('slow');
        $('a').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#information').slideDown('slow');
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        if(this.id == 'about'){
            $('#information').animate({
            left: "0"
            }, 1000);

        } else {
            $('#information').animate({
            left: "-100%"
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a side question to the main one I had, but should you by any chance then also know:

If "Contact" is clicked on first. That it shows the "Contact" content, before it slides down?

Because right now it slides down (correctly), but it shows the "About" content first, and then slides to the "contact" content.

Comment: So that it displays the right content for which menu link is clicked.

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect!

Comment: Hey again, I'm not sure if you should have the answer, but I tried to put in a "push" function instead using animate+css function instead of slide. The issue I have is the sliding left/right with the different two pages. [link]https://jsfiddle.net/MSChristensen/zqup4ryv/15/

Comment: You were able to create it before, somehow I broke it :S Would be very grateful if I could have your input once again.

Comment: One very last thing and I promise this will be the last one. If I want to add more menu links. How do I then make sure that if the "about"/"contact" page is active, that it closes it/push back up, and then shows the next page. Kind regards Morten

Comment: Ohh forgot something. Would it also be possible for it to push the general page down (right now only menu there). But when it is clicked it push it all down. Which means the menu is still visible below it. Would that be possible?